# How to detect changes in a native drop down menu via python?

Tags: scripting

How do I detect changes(updates) in a native drop down menu in the UI via python?

Comment: The drop down is likely an enumerated property list. 

bpy.props.EnumProperty(items, name="", description="", default=None, options={'ANIMATABLE'}, update=None, get=None, set=None)

Use the "update=" to call a function on change.
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html

Comment: previous comment should be an answer.

Comment: @Ratt Thank you for the link. I also found these: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?341961-automatically-update-EnumProperty-from-UI-Panel&p=2680268&viewfull=1#post2680268  Both examples are with menus created by the script, but how do I detect changes in a native Blender drop down menu? It is the camera drop down menu in the scene strip settings of the sequencer I'm after.

Comment: @tintwotin Best i can suggest at the moment is to edit your question to specify detecting changes in a native property. Based on your description it looks to be the camera override selection scene.sequence_editor.active_strip.scene_camera